# New pci-e video card makes computer not boot

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, pci-express

I'm trying to upgrade the video card on my Dell Vostro 460 mini tower (from 2011, i5 3.something GHz, 4GB RAM). The card is a "Gigabyte Radeon R7 250X 1GB 1x HDMI, 1x DVI, 2x Display Port PCI-e". This card has a 6 pin power supply connector.

I've upgrade the standard 300W PSU to 630W (the card's box states the power requirement as '450W (or greater) with one 75W pci-e power connector recommended'.

Whatever configuration I've tried, the machine won't boot with the new card in it. And by 'no booting' I mean, after pressing the power button, all fans rotate, the disks make their little startup clickety-clack sound, but the machine never gets past POST -- nothing happens.

Also no beep-errors, no 'light' error codes.

BIOS is at its up-to-date-est (A06).

I *think* the pci-e on the motherboard is a version 2.0 (but who knows, it's Dell).

Things I've tried:

- machine runs fine with new PSU (ie, in the old configuration, without the new card). Replace old pci-e dual DVI card by new card: no boot. Put old card back: pc runs fine.
- swap working dual DVI card by 265MB single DisplayPort card: pc runs fine.
- put in new card, disconnect all components from motherboard and only leave 1 bank or RAM: nothing happens.
- the card came with an adapter to power the card through the 6 pin pci-e power adapter with two molex plugs from the PSU: nothing happens.

Conclusion: PSU is fine, PCIE slot is fine, GPU is dead?

At the moment I do not have alternative hardware to test the GPU in.

I've already RMA'd two units, the manufacturer has sent me new ones without cost. And I'm now on the third one, and it's also not doing anything at all. Manufacturer has stated that the first 2 units were 'defective', has supplied no further info.

What's going on?

Comment: would be nice to know if they're really sending you defective cards or if "it was defective" is their way of saying "don't worry about it". Or even more curiously, if your computer is somehow killing them

Answer (score 1):

Not enough rep to just post this is a comment.

Have you tried the card in another slot? I've had motherboards that only let me put my graphics cards in either the closest or farthest slot from the CPU. In fact, my current system only boots with it in the farthest away slot.

Otherwise, the only obvious answer would be that the graphics card is dead. The odds of having 3 DOA are incredibly slim though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My motherboard only has a single 16x slot.